# Update WordPress from 3.6.1 to 3.8.1

Tags: wordpress

If i update the WordPress version from 3.6.1  to 3.8.1 will my existing databases, plugins and theme be deleted and will be updated freshly? Can any one tell me about this.

Comment: it only updates the wordpress core, and leaves plugins and themes intact, until you ask it to upgrade those. the database may undergo some schema changes if the core wordpress schema has changed between the versions, but the content will remain. as always, backup files and database before upgrading.

Comment: if you mean backup - i recommend backing up both the files AND database prior to upgrading. 99% of the time it will run fine and you won't need the backup, but if you skip this step then chances are that will be the one time you'll need it :)

Comment: my database contains japan languages, so if i export that to my local the content inside the table is showing only "???".. how can i take the database backup from PHP MyAdmin, as the database is very huge.

Comment: As @flauntster said, most of the times, nothing will break, so you should have a seamless update. However, I would recommend you take a backup of your files and database and disable all plugins before you do the upgrade.